# set_time_limit(0) and "Maximum execution time" PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a script where I have set:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

but still get

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in /home/Feed.php on line 234
```

I've also tried setting:

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

in the .htaccess file but still can't stop this error - any ideas why this is not overriding?

Comment: Your host overrides your override?, if you place `set_time_limit(0)` within the loop it will reset time back to 0 on each iteration.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone are you sure?

Comment: Just to let know that this `set_time_limit(XX)` solved my problem. Perhaps different hosts have different rules/configurations. The `php_value max_execution_time XX` didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, your host is running a copy of PHP with the Suhoshin patch installed. This patch provides a large number of security and operational enhancements to PHP, including allowing the host to disable functions like `set_time_limit()`.

There are other ways a host could disable the `set_time_limit()` function, but that's the most likely. (especially as you've already ruled out Safe Mode)

Why would they disable this function? Because a PHP function that takes a long time to run also typically takes a lot of server resources; in a shared hosting environment, it is wise for the host to mitigate this kind of thing to avoid having a rogue script impact other users.

What can you do about it?

Firstly, are you sure you need to set the time limit? Do you know why your script takes that much time to run? Can you work around it? Perhaps doing a bit of profiling on your code might help you find the bottlenecks and speed up the program.

Alternatively, if you really do need to set the time limit, you may need to ask your host to enable you to do so, or else upgrade your package or switch hosting providers.

Comment: How patch is differen from disable_functions directive?

Answer (score 3):

This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it isn't running in safe mode...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

"When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero."

So you could, theoretically, `call set_time_limit(0)` repeatedly.

However, it is possible for your hosting provider to prevent that via safe mode, etc.

Honestly, I'd just try to get a cheap VPS where you control things if you need to customize that sort of thing.

Comment: The manual said that "If set to zero, no time limit is imposed."

Comment: Yes. But the point is, setting it to 0 isn't enough for him apparently. So using it to reset the counter may be viable. I never tried to abuse it that way but it supposedly works.